# Ugly OpenJDK fonts

Tags: fonts, openjdk

Is there a way to make OpenJDK 7 fonts look exactly the same as Oracle JDK 7 fonts?
I use Intellij IDEA and today tried it with OpenJDK, but fonts look ugly.
I tried several tricks with awt.useSystemAAFontSettings=on / lcd and swing.aatext=true? but with no luck - it is still ugly.

I tried to google that issue but there is not much info. I want just the same fonts as in Oracle JDK...

Answer (score 3):

this might be a quick fix .. though not exactly what asked

from http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=210664

m_gol 2012-04-05 09:59:40 UTC

Just for others that potentially could experience this problem I think some
specific instructions might be useful (following these steps has an advantage
of not messing your Ubuntu's JDK, it will only affect Netbeans):

1) Download JDK from:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u3-download-1501626.html

2) Unpack it to your home directory (you'll get a jdk1.7.0_03 directory)

3) Start the installer from the command line with:

```
$ sudo su
# JAVA_HOME="$HOME/jdk1.7.0_03/" ./netbeans-7.1.1-ml-linux.sh
```

4) After installation create a script with the following contents (and name it
netbeans):

```
#!/bin/sh
JAVA_HOME="$HOME/jdk1.7.0_03/" /usr/local/netbeans-7.1.1/bin/netbeans &>/dev/null &
```

5) Copy a created script to /usr/local/bin

6) Now you can start netbeans by pressing Alt+F2, writing netbeans and pressing
Enter